# Why is the Citizen Patrol badge awarded in a different way than Deputy / Marshal badges?

Tags: discussion, flags, badges, helpful-flags

I'm pretty new on the site so I might be wrong, but from what I understand from the descriptions of the "Deputy" and "Marshal" badges, your flags have to be labelled as helpful by a moderator. I flagged my first post as duplicate today and I got the "Citizen Patrol" instantly without moderator checking. What's the reason behind that ? A new user is most likely to flag something incorrectly the first time than afterwards and I see no point why should anyone be praised for a mistake.

Comment: Duplicate and "should be closed" flags are not handled by a moderator. The post is pushed into the vote to close review queue (if it is not already pushed by any other flag/vote) where people with privilege to close vote review it.

Comment: But from your profile, it's not been marked helpful _yet_. So deleted my answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Citizen Patrol badge like various other single action bronze badges e.g. Supporter (First upvote), Critic (First downvote) are there to aid discovery of features. We're trying to get people to gain a basic knowledge of the things they can do and get a little bit of instant gratification.

Delayed gratification is so much more complicated, you're asking someone new to the process to remember what they did last time they logged in that got them the badge.

Beyond that there are silver and gold badges, to earn them you need to learn to do things properly.