# Citizen Patrol badge - Inconsistency in the [flag-badges]

Tags: support, flags, badges, flag-badges

I recently raised my first flag on Meta but even few day later I still hadn't award the "Citizen Patrol" badge ([badge doc page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)) as can see here:

[image]

I did some research but found none. When I was trying to think about it, the only answer that fit, was the "Citizen Patrol" (in contrast to "Deputy" and "Marshal") is giving after **flagging a post and not comment** (my flag was on comment) as his description:

> First flagged post

Is this true?
If it is, should we make all those 3 badge the same? (in the matter of post only or both flag for comment and post?)

Today, all the group badges has the same way of earning them and the different is by the number for each. For example:

> Excavator: Edit first post that was inactive for 6 months
>
> Archaeologist: Edit 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months

They are the same but for 1 post and 100 post. They are many other example but I think the point is clear...

I found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366284/why-is-the-citizen-patrol-badge-awarded-in-a-different-way-than-deputy-marshal) question - it also taking about the differences between the flagging badge but from other perspective (should the flag consider "helpful" or not). Also on this issue we have inconsistency between the [flag-badges](/questions/tagged/flag-badges)

Comment: Yes, the badge description says: first flagged **post** so flagged comments won't contribute to that badge. Also note that the daily limit of flags you can raise is also separated. I can raise 100 post flags and 100 comments flags per day.

Comment: @rene - that what I saw and deduce from that description - just want to make sure. How should I change my post to be more about the best practice (in my option) that they should be consistence?

Comment: Why should they be consistent?

Comment: Because currently all the group badge as the same with the action and the way you earn them and different only in the bar (the score / the days / the post number ...)

Comment: The first revision's title was scary: "Citizen Control..."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no need for consistency.

A badge is earned for a carefully selected set of criteria.

I do think flagging a post and having it done correctly (pick the right reason) is worth a badge. With a bit of luck you get a comment flag right at the first try (just flag a comment with a swear word in it).

The badges you can earn for moderation activities are fine. Their criteria doesn't need changing and there is not enough evidence, except anecdotal, that these descriptions and their criteria cause great up-roar or lots of Meta complaints.

Leave it as is.

Comment: Do notice the first flag doesn't has to be correct (as you saying) - look at the link in my question - it is not must to be helpful.

Comment: Even more awesome